# Remote invocation in EJB 3.0

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, ejb, rmi, javabeans

I'm new to EJB 3.0 and trying out the DI with my ejb's.

I'm using WAS 7.0 as my appserver and I have two EAR's deployed on it. Both have ejb 3 session beans and I need to invoke an ejb in ear 2 from an ejb available in ear 1.

In both my applications, I have a client project which holds the local and remote interfaces, a *commons* project which contains interfaces which are extended by the remote and local interfaces, then the ejb project and a router project(as the webservice endpoints for the ejb's)

Now to make the remote call, I tried putting the client and commons jar files in the lib directory of EAR, updated the META-INF of the ejb project and tried to use the @EJB annotation, but its giving exceptions, that the EJB's are missing.

I tried to do a JNDI lookup, but it gave NamingException.

Which is the correct way to do a remote bean invoke in ejb 3.0?

Please provide your suggestions.

Comment: Please post the exception message,  stack, and causes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the invocation, the problem is getting a reference to the EJB's stub in the first place. For a remote EJB, this absolutely requires a JNDI lookup (unless you want to call it via SOAP or REST). Thus, you need to add the `lookup` parameter to the `@EJB` annotation, and you need to pass it the correct JNDI lookup name - and that is the difficult part since the composition of JNDI names is complex and influenced by a lot of factors.

Comment: WAS 7.0 is JavaEE 5 and does not support the lookup element of the @EJB annotation.  WAS does not support mappedName, so the only mechanism available available is ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml or to configure the bindings at deployment time.  The naming rules for EJB bindings are complex, but the default is reasonably simple: "ejb/{app}/{module}.jar/{BeanName}#{com.example.InterfaceName}"